# What does the "S" mean?

Tags: notation

[image: Snippet from "The Addams Family"]

At first I thought "S" was similar to a glissando, but then there's a spot with an S and a glissando.  What does the S mean?

Comment: Is this electric bass guitar or acoustic upright bass?   If the latter, we need to know whether this is an arco or pizz passage

Comment: I would guess slide.

Comment: Reminds me of glissando notation where the "gliss." isn't visible over short enough wiggly lines.

Comment: The passage is for Electric bass (and optionally fretless.)

Answer (score 1):

The S probably means "slide" which is another word for glissando. In your example only one of them has a wavy line but they should probably all have a wavy line. In my music notation program it sometimes happens that the wavy line isn't printed if there is a short distance between the notes in which  case only the letter or word is printed. Personally I always write the word "gliss." instead of a single letter, because the term "gliss." makes it clear what is intended. Then if the line (whether straight or wavy) isn't printed I spend some time working with the matter until I manage to get the program to print the line.

Answer (score -3):

The 2 S's in measures 29 and 31 may stand for "Subject" which is a motive which is stated and developed throughout the work.In J.S. Bach's inventions he stated a Subject ( or a motive ) early in each piece which was often associated with a complementary motive called a "Countersubject". The Subject and Countersubject would be recurring often in two-part counterpoint.Another famous "S" motive is developed in Ludwig van Beethoven's 5th Symphony...- Da da da Daaa , Da da da Daaa .Just those 4 notes in that one Subject ( motive ) and his 5th Symphony was created. A super theme develops out of 4 simple notes. The Subject = S